# javascript not working in wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am developing my custom theme in word press. But my java script file is not working. In chrome console only this message shows `JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1`. But my JavaScript file is not working.

Header.php code

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>Freelancer - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e8beb482c3.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Footer.php code

```
<div class="footer-below">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        Copyright &copy; Your Website 2017
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</footer>
<?php wp_footer();?>
</body>
</html>
```

Function.php code

```html
<?php 

add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
function b2w_theme_styles() {
 wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_css' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');      
 wp_enqueue_style('style_css' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'); 
}

add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'b2w_Theme_styles');

function b2w_theme_js(){        
 wp_enqueue_script( 'contact_me_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/contact_me.js', array('jquery', '', true) );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jqBootstrapValidation_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js', array('jquery', '', true) );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jqueryeasing_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.min.js', array('jquery', '', true) );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'freelancer_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/freelancer.min.js', array('jquery', '', true) );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery', '', true) );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', array('jquery', '', true) );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'popper_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/popper.min.js', array('jquery', '', true) );        
}
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'b2w_theme_js');
?>
```

And in index.php i use this code for calling header and footer along with my html code `<?php get_header();?> , <?php get_footer(); ?>`

Comment: "But my JavaScript file is not working" is a very useless explanation of what is wrong. Especially when there is no JavaScript in the code you pasted. What is expected and actual behaviour? Also please remove all PHP and post the rendered HTML AND JavaScript into ONE snippet in a [mcve]

Comment: At least ensure you enqueue your jquery source before anything else that needs jquery

Comment: please tell me i link correctly my java script files or not..because all of my code is working fine but the issue is java script animation is not working like bootstrap model.

Comment: my issue is you please check my function.php file and tell me i am doing right or not

Comment: contact_me_js is written by u??

Comment: if so add it last

Comment: Actually, I think wp enqueues jquery.js by default. Check that first. Remove duplicate script sources and check they are rendered in proper order.

Comment: ok i do this but problem is still

Comment: Now i use this sequence

Comment: wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', array('jquery', '', true) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popper_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/popper.min.js', array('jquery', '', true) );

Comment: load all the js of  plugins first
then the js which you have written

Comment: you mean i convert this code   array('jquery', '', true)  as like this array()

Comment: wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', array('jquery', '', true) ); this should be before your contact_me_js.js

Comment: yes like that way

Comment: Still Problem  @AkshayShah

Comment: bootstrap and various others need jQuery, so jQuery should be enqueued first I guess

Comment: yes you right and i place all of these as like you say but problem is same

Comment: ok, I'm not really experienced with wordpress development, so wait for someone to help. In the meantime maybe edit your post and show the content of your own javascript file, maybe it has errors in it...

Comment: Please update your question as mplungjan suggests. We are not mind readers... **we cannot help you until you give us the information we need**. What do you mean by "not working"? What is expected to happen? Are you getting errors? Where is the code that's going wrong? What have you tried to debug the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
  wp_enqueue_script('my-custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/my-custom-script.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
```

Much has changed with WP script loading since this article was posted. These days, WordPress automatically loads jQuery for you, whenever some other script requires it. The smart loading requires that you specify jquery as the $deps parameter when enqueuing your other JavaScript files, for example: